# Why does this jQuery OOP property became undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, properties, undefined

Why does the property of this code is not showing after the click event?

Property `this.ContainerId` became undefined when it entered the `this.ShoutCount` method.

Thank you.

```js
var table = function (containerId) {
  this.ContainerId = containerId;
  
  this.ShoutCount = function (totalC) {
        var label = $("#" + this.ContainerId + " .result").text();
        alert(totalC + " " + label);
  }
  this.ClickCount = function (sc) {
    $("#" + this.ContainerId + " .showTotalCount").click(function () {
      sc($(this).text());
    });
  }
  this.ClickCount(this.ShoutCount);
}

var t = new table("user-tab-pagination");
```

```html
<div id="user-tab-pagination">
  <div class="search-count"><span class="showTotalCount">100</span> <span class="result">Result(s)</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this belong to particular context and you are using it in inside function so this is override there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because once you enter the `ShoutCount` method, `this` is scoped to that method, not to the outer method. You need to use `bind` to attach the scope you want, e.g.

```
this.ShoutCount = function (totalC) {
  var label = $("#" + this.ContainerId + " .result").text();
  alert(totalC + " " + label);
}.bind(this);
```